# I'm writing a javascript code to take two inputs from user and and check if letter is present in sentence.But the if block isn't being executed

Tags: javascript

This JavaScript code takes two inputs through user input scen and letter through HTML from. I want this code to be able to check if the sentence contains the letter, if yes then the sentence should be printed after the first coinsurance of the letter but this code is not working. I'm getting 0 as output every time.

```js
    function myFunction(){
     
      var scen = document.getElementById('scen').innerText;
      var letter = document.getElementById('letter').innerText;
      let err = "No such letter found"
      let result = scen.indexOf(letter);
      var len = scen.length;
      
      if(result>=0)
        {
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
          document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = len;
          document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = scen.substring(result+1);
        }
      
      else{
        document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = err;
      }
      
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <body>



      <p>Find a letter:</p>

      <form id="chk" method="post">
        <label for="scen">Enter a sentence</label>
        <input type="text" name="scen" id="scen" placeholder="Enter a scentence"><br><br>
        <label for="letter">Enter the letter you want to find</label>
        <input type="text" name="letter" id="letter" placeholder="Enter a letter" min="1">
        <br>
        <button type="button" onClick="myFunction()">Check</button>
      </form>



      <p id="demo"></p>
      <p id="demo2"></p>
      <p id="demo3"></p>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: To get the value of an `<input>` element you need the `.value` property, not `.innerText`.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing Your line with

```
var letter = document.getElementById('letter').value;
```

The element with id `letter` is an Input, therefore to get the letter that user types in You need to use the `value` property

Additionally, I would recommend trying to debug the program. In this particular case, a couple of logs like `console.log("Letter value is: ", letter)` would surely help identifying the issue.